# Assigning a disabled/non-existent shipping code to order

Tags: shipping-methods, integrate

I am working on an integration between Magento and a third-party ERP system. This ERP handles all payment and shipping on each order and tracking information is passed back to Magento for later use.

All orders will be shipped for free, so I only have Free Shipping enabled in Magento. When the order arrives in the ERP for processing, a CSR will determine the best shipping method for that particular order and this info gets pushed back to Magento when an order is ready to be invoiced/shipped.

When this info gets back to Magento, I need to update the order's shipping method with a new description and (optionally) a new shipping code. In order for customers to be able to view tracking information, I'd like to assign a shipping code to an order and this code might match up with generic shipping codes in Magento (FedEx, UPS, USPS, etc) though it might not.

**Am I safe assigning a disabled shipping method to an order?**

My assumption is that it should be fine, as it seems entirely plausible that in a typical Magento store, a shipping method might have been enabled in the past but disabled currently as the store owner decided to switch carriers. In this case, the now disabled method on the order should still continue to provide requested info to the user.